# mce: Hardware error

Tags: kernel

Turned computer on this morning and after a few reboots, I saw this in the logs:

```
kernel: [    0.032415] mce: CPU supports 7 MCE banks
kernel: [    0.044000] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
kernel: [    0.044000] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 4: fe00000000070f0f
kernel: [    0.044000] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR fe97c024 MISC c012000001000000 
kernel: [    0.044000] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 2:600f12 TIME 1553935675 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 600063e
```

Most of the advice says install mcelog, but this isn't available in the repositories any more.

Comment: Tried using rasdaemon, but:
rasdaemon: Can't parse MCE for this AMD CPU yet

Answer (score 1):

`mcelog` was removed in Debian 10+ (Buster) and [Ubuntu 18.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mcelog/+bug/1752251)+

The functionality has been replaced by `rasdaemon`. Unfortunately the version of [rasdaemon in Ubuntu 18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/rasdaemon) is old and is currently missing some functionality (eg: AMD CPU).