# Mce hardware error with dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 22.04, disk

I have a PC with a dual boot Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS / Windows 11 on two separate disks that worked for several months. At the moment, Windows works perfectly well but, when I boot on Ubuntu I get this error message:

```
mce: [Hardware Error] : CPU 11: Machine Check: 0 Bank 5: bea0000000000108
mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR ffffffc051b4f4
mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 2: a20f12 TIME 1697973800 SOCKET 0 APIC b microcode a20120a
/dev/sda2: recovering journal
/dev/sda2: clean, 515106/30498816 files, 74785580/121965056 blocks
```

I have the same problem when I boot on live USB.

I've tried several things, but as I don't have an internet connection I can't get `mcelog`, nor `rasdaemon` nor `scmartclt` as recommended [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129862/mce-hardware-error).
When I boot into recovery mode, I no longer have access to the Internet despite various actions such as [here](https://superuser.com/questions/328800/missing-eth0-ethernet-interface-in-ubuntu-cant-connect-to-router), [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118850/no-wired-ethernet-connection), and [here](https://vitux.com/how-to-configure-networking-with-netplan-on-ubuntu/) (the PC crashes). But I don't know whether this problem is related to the error described above or not.

As recommended in other posts, I ran a memtest, with no problem found. Since Windows works fine, I don't see how the problem could come from RAM, CPU or GPU.

Another thing I noticed, which may be related, is that in the boot menu the tab for Ubuntu is linked to the WD Blue SN570 1TB drive, which is the drive containing Windows (Ubuntu is on Samsung SSD 870 EVO 500GB).
We can see on this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uAAQ.jpg) the boot menu where `ubuntu (WD Blue SN570 1TB)` is the first choice.